# How can I produce multiple webpages with a different output based on one entry/Page/custom Page?

Tags: custom-post-types, themes, templates

**My problem:**

I have a custom page format for events. Now I would like to get different outputs for each of these events.

1. Normal webpage › for visitors
2. Custom look › for easy copy and paste to other platforms for seminars.

**My question**

Is it possible to design two templates with different URLs. So that I have the possibility to call these pages with custom templates/designs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Query string parameters** are a helpful friend in this situation. It will allow you to keep the same single-$posttype.php file for both formats of the page.

So if someone visits your page using the URL:

`https://yourwebsite.com/events`

They will see your normal webpage for visitors. But if someone uses the URL:

`https://yourwebsite.com/events?seminar=true`

They will see something completely different.

This is accomplished by using the `$_GET` global variable provided by PHP. Documentation is [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php).

So you could do the following using a `single-event.php` page (providing event is a post type):

```
<?php
$is_seminar = $_GET['seminar'];

if ( $is_seminar === 'true' ) : ?>
  <h1>Custom look for seminars.</h1>
<?php else : ?>
  <h1>Normal webpage</h1>
<?php endif;
```

Or if you want a little bit of a cleaner look to your URL, take a look at [Get URL query string parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8469767/get-url-query-string-parameters) using `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`. Also see [How can I make different page templates for one category?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/31073/how-can-i-make-different-page-templates-for-one-category?rq=1) for another alternative solution using your post's meta info.

Comment: Hey @Dcfunkster – Thank you very much for your help. I tried your solution. It works ;)